# Require just email address to enter site

Tags: wordpress, email, authentication, analytics

I have a client who wants a site that requires people to provide their email address before entering every time. Kind of like a user login but with just an email address. The basic idea is to be able to see when each email is visiting the site and where it is going so he can send info to that address based on what they are viewing on the site.

I am working with wordpress and have recommended making the site availible only to regisered users, then tracking that activity with a plugin like wp-activity. However he does not want people visiting the site to have to remember a password. He just wants to be able to track the user activity by email address.

Is there any way to do accomplish this without requiring a user to register with an email address and password?

Comment: He's going to get a lot of `asdf@asdf.com`..

Comment: if you want users register with email make sure the email is valid and using confirmation email to validate

Comment: @Blorgbeard - wordpress has a function to activate user by sending authentication mail. so all the supposed asdf@asdf.com will be nulled

Comment: you should at least verify the email address before sending any mail...

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work, but I did not tested it :

```
function o99_my_email_login($user, $pass) {
    global $wpdb;
    if (is_email($user)) {
        $found = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT user_login FROM $wpdb->users WHERE user_email = '%s'", $user));
        $user = $found ? $found : $user;
    } else {
        $user = 1; // or $username = 1; ??
    }
    return;
}
add_action('wp_authenticate', 'o99_my_email_login', 10, 2);
```

Also this similar function works , but I am not sure as to it´s security..

```
add_action('wp_authenticate','o99_smsa_allow_email_login');


function o99_smsa_allow_email_login($username) {
 $user = get_user_by_email($username);
 if(!empty($user->user_login))
 $username = $user->user_login;
 return $username;
}
```

or just use a ready made plugin like [this one : CLICK](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-email-login/)